# bind to scope when inside an if/else-statement not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Inside my controller, I have:

```
$scope.friends = userService.data.user.friends
```

However, if `user` is `null`, I obviously get an error because `userService.data.user.friends` cannot be accessed.

So, now I use:

```
if(userService.data.user){
    $scope.friends = userService.data.user.friends;
}else{
     $scope.friends = null;
}
```

**Problem is:** `if statement` is not bound to `$scope`, and therefore is evaluated only `once`. So, if `userService.data.user` is initally null `$scope.friends` is also evaluated to `null`, `but stays null even if friends are added to`userService.data.user`later on` (by $http request, for example)

I need to reload the route to get the new value of `userService.data.user.friends`.

How did I get scope bound to `userService.data.user.friends`, but also handle the `null` case ?

Comment: $http get's stuff asynchronously. You must return a promise from the service and then populate the $scope at the controller.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. Problem is how to handle `if statment`

Comment: You must handle this If inside the promise. You are getting this error because the $http doesn't returned the data at the time when the if statement get called.

Comment: @Fals `$timeout` is also asynchronous and returns promise. Angular makes some magic for us if know how to use it

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski the $timeout it's a service implementation for the setTimeout. It'll block the exection until ends. The $timeout also triggers $$diggest method from the $scope. The $$diggest do the magic, not the $timeout service.

Comment: @Fals What part of code will block execution? $timeout only triggers `if (!skipApply) $rootScope.$apply();` and `$browser.defer()`

Answer (score 0):

Service $parse – https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $parse, userService) {
  $scope.friends = $parse('data.user.friends')(userService)
  $scope.someDeepProperty = $parse('data.user.friends.data.deep')(userService) || 'we are so deep';
})
.factory('userService', function($timeout) {
  var userService = {}
  
  userService.data = {
    user: {
      friends: []
    }
  }
  
  $timeout(function() {
    userService.data.user.friends.push({name: 'foo'})
  }, 2000);
  
  return userService;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    Friends: {{ friends }} - wait 2 seconds for update <br>
    Deep property: {{ someDeepProperty }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it's the syntax?